# Oracle Database Installation Error "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error"

Tags: database, windows, oracle, oracle12c

I'm working on a Mavericks machine running a Windows 8.1 VM, trying to install an Oracle Database 12c. The installation runs fine up until it gets to the Database Configuration Assistant portion, where it immediately gives me the error mentioned above, "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error".

The database installer gives the option to skip a step, so I've tried doing so, and the database installation continues and completes. After it is completed, the Database Configuration Assistant is installed as an application. Running this application gives the same error immediately after setting some of the basic information (like database name, password, etc.).

I'm more or less brand new to Oracle databases, and I have no clue as to what this error might mean, or how to fix it. Does anybody have any idea as to why this error is appearing? I'm eager to provide any more information if it's needed, and would greatly appreciate any ideas or tips.

Thanks!

Comment: SO is for questions about _programming_.  Your question is off-topic because it appears to be about installing Oracle.  It's probably on-topic at [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your oracle database is not up and running, this is a common issue for some first time users, what you need is to setup your database before anything else.

Try going to Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Restart both OracleXETNSListener and the OracleServiceXE.

Or just go to start Start >> Run >> type "services.msc"

search for OracleXETNSListener and OracleServiceXE, right click then hit Start.